# nodejs error when i try to run a file with jquery in it

Tags: node.js

also when i run 
node script.js page.html          i have this error, i dont know why, i did put jquery in my dependencies and it installed it

> C:\Users\NEBELYN\Desktop\projects1\paragraph\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:29
>
> throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
>                                                 ^                                                             Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
>
> ```
> at module.exports (C:\Users\NEBELYN\Desktop\projects1\paragraph\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:29:1
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NEBELYN\Desktop\projects1\paragraph\script.js:9:1)          
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                                  
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                                    
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                                      
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                                            
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)                                                          
> at startup (node.js:119:16)                                                                            
> at node.js:902:3
> ```

here is the code am running

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv,
    $ = require('jquery'),
    fs = require('fs');

var file = argv._[0];

var html = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');

$(html).find('p').each(function(index) {
    var content = $(this).html();

    console.log('Paragraph ' + (index + 1) + ': ' + content);
});
```

and here is the page.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Apple</p>
    <span>Unrelated</span>
    <p>Orange</p>

    <div>
        Steak
    </div>

    <p>Banana</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery requires a full DOM implementation, which you don't have on the server.

To parse HTML text, you should use a simpler library called [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), which has a jQuery-like API but does not use a DOM.

Alternatively, you could use JSDOM to fake a browser DOM on the server (this is slower).

Comment: thanks, but i am following a tutorial and the persons code compiled, i dont know why mine didnt

Answer (score 2):

I had code that worked fine a month ago, but started to display this error when I upgraded to the latest jquery via npm.  If I only knew how to get back that older version, then the problem would go away.

This seems to have fixed it:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jsdom



// Define window
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var window = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();
var $ = require("jquery")( window );
```